# ng-show selecting different true-false methods with buttons

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I'm trying to show/hide elements by pressing buttons.

```
    <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="dateFilter = computeShow(event.date)">Upcoming Events</a>
    <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="dateFilter = computeToday(event.date)">Today Events</a>
    <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="dateFilter = true">All the events</a>
```

In the view I have an ng-show that is equal to dateFilter:

```
    <section ng-repeat="event in events" ng-show="dateFilter">
```

and I have the logic in the app.js

```
    $scope.computeShow = function(date){
      return (moment().format() <= date);
    }

    $scope.computeToday = function(date){
      return (moment().format() == date)
    }
```

But when I press the button of "upcoming events" or "Today events", it is always false and none of the events are shown. The button to show all the events works perfectly. The default behavior before pressing any button is "false", so none of the events are shown.

I tried to do:

```
    ng-click="dateFilter = 'computeShow(event.date)'"
    ng-click="dateFilter = 'computeToday(event.date)'"
```

but it is always true and shows all the events.

Why is not working? where can I put "computeShow(event.date)" as default?

Edit: I tried to add

```
    $scope.dateFilter = 'computeShow(event.date)';
```

to have a default behavior but this is always "true" and I also tried

```
    $scope.dateFilter = computeShow(event.date);
```

and this one is always false

I add a fiddle with what I am trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/28f4edv3/6/

Comment: Have a look this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099496/angular-js-ng-click-scope-set-doesnt-work-in-ng-if. Why cant you assing $scope.dateFilter = True | False in your both function and use it in ng-show. The default will be True. In this case you don't need to assign it on ng-click and just need to call function.

Comment: When I run your fiddle the console tells me that "moment" is not defined.

Comment: I forgot to include the moment.js library, now it is included and I see the same than in my project, everything disappears

Comment: @Alex your fiddle seems to work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your buttons, you are passing `event` which is `undefined`, since the buttons are not in the scope of `ng-repeat`. I have modified the logic. It will work the way you want it to.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
        <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="showEvents = 'upcomming'">Upcoming Events</a> <br> 
        <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="showEvents = 'today'">Today Events</a> <br> 
        <a id="filter-by-date" class="btn btn-success wide-btn" href="#" ng-click="showEvents = 'all'">All the events</a> <br><br>

        <section ng-repeat="event in events" ng-show="computeShow(event, showEvents)">{{event.title}}</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.dateFilter = 'computeShow(event.date)';

    $scope.computeShow = function (event, showEvents) {
        if (showEvents === 'upcomming' && moment(event.date).isAfter(moment())) {
            return true;
        } else if (showEvents === 'today' && moment().isSame(event.date, 'day')) {
            return true;
        } else if (showEvents === 'all') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    $scope.events = [{
        title: "hello",
        date: "2015-11-29"
    }, {
        title: "awesome event",
        date: "2015-12-1"
    }, {
        title: "another event",
        date: "2015-10-31"
    }, {
        title: "fancy event",
        date: "2015-12-2"
    }, {
        title: "today event",
        date: "2015-12-1"
    }, ];

}]);
```

**[See the Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/msmzeLe3/)**

Here I am using `moment` functions `isAfter`, `isSame` to compare dates.

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you a lot. I like the isAfter and isSame solution, glad to learn it. Now I'm trying to set the upcoming as default, because now as default is false and shows nothing until I press some button.

Comment: @Alex add **ng-init="showEvents = 'upcomming'"** to 2nd div (i.e. ng-controller div).

Comment: when I add ng-init="showEvents = 'upcomming'" to 2nd div it shows upcoming by default, but then the buttons don not change the filter, it remains upcomming even I press some button

Comment: My bad, I put ng-init="showEvents = 'upcoming'" in two different places, now its only in one place and it works perfect. Thank you again.